# Common Lisp: read each input character as a list element

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Lisp newbie here.

I want to read from standard-in a string of characters such as:

```
aabc
```

I want to convert that input into a list, where each character becomes a list element:

```
(a a b c)
```

And I want the list assigned to a global variable, `text`.

I created this function:

```
(defun get-line ()
    (setf text (read)))
```

but that just results in assigning a single symbol to `text`, not tokenizing the input into a list of symbols.

What's the right way to implement `get-line()` please?

Comment: Do you want those characters as atoms or chars?

Comment: Each character should become an atom.

Comment: Is case significant?

Comment: Thanks for pulling these things out of me, @tobyodavies. Yes, case is significant. So if the input is aabc then the resulting list should be (a a b c).

Comment: The thing is in common lisp, the list (eq '(a b c d) '(A B C D)) in both of those, all the atoms are considered upper case.

Comment: Why not try it yourself? Lisp programming isn't that difficult. If you are really have no idea what to do, reading input is done with READ and the function to explode a symbol into pieces is usually called EXPLODE. You would need to google for it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: First using *coerce* to convert the string to a list of characters, then *mapcar* to convert each character to a string.

```
(defun get-line ()
    (setf text (mapcar 'string (coerce (string (read)) 'list))))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(loop
   for x = (string-upcase (string (read-char)))
   while (not (equal " " x))
   collecting (intern x))
```

Note the upcase is there because symbols in CL are not case sensitive and are upcased by default by the reader.